# Load code for custom fields only on admin pages?

Tags: custom-field

Is this possible?

I have big chunk of code for creating and saving custom meta fields, and I have a feeling that this has some impact on wordpress loading time (**?**).

I tried with

```
add_action('init', 'admin_only');

function admin_only() {
    if ( is_admin() ){
        require_once('functions_admin.php');
    }
}
```

but on **"add new post"** screen custom fields are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading this code won't have big impact on loading times.

Of course you should make sure, that this code is only executed when it should be...

But yes, it should be possible. Just make sure you don't use it to early (when `is_admin()` return incorrect value).

**EDIT**

The code you've posted here should work just fine. Of course you have to make sure that code placed in `functions_admin.php` is written correctly (for example you have to take care of using global variables in correct way).

To test if this is included, just add `echo 'alamakota';` in first line of this included file and check if 'alamakota' is showing on every admin page (it should).

Also make sure that you don't add filters/actions to hooks that are run before `init` hook. The won't fire up (WordPress already called these hooks before you added your filters). See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: It loads functions_admin.php, so probably it's not loading too early, but no custom fields are loaded

Comment: what is inside of this `functions_admin.php` file?

Comment: It's too long for comment
http://chopapp.com/#77k2ugfx

Comment: Problem lies on line 3 of your shortened code. You include this code inside of function, so `$meta_box` is no longer global variable. Just make it global or place this variable inside of `mytheme_add_box` function.

Comment: But why does it work when I put the exact same code in functions.php

Comment: Because then your `$meta_box` variable is global. If you include it outside of function it will be global too. But if you do it inside function it is local and not global. But it shouldn't be global - just put this variable inside function that uses it. Good practice is not to use global variables unless it's really necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll try to make it work!

Comment: Don't have to try anything. Just don't use global variables, when you don't have to - in this case you can move it inside function, and in other cases too, I guess.

Comment: No problem. Just mark this answer as correct, if it solved your problem.